# relative path not working in html attribute in .php file

Tags: php, html, path

I tried to use a URL in the parent directory of the root but it's not working in the HTML attribute of the PHP file.

```
<?php 
    include ("../func.php"); // working, will include the file in the parent directory 
?>  
<img src='../testimg.png'/>  <!-- It only looks inside the current directory-->  
<img src='..../../testimg.png'/>   <!-- If I mess around with the relative path, it still looks inside the current directory-->
```

However, if I delete the PHP code and change the file extension to .html, the relative path in img src works normally.

Why is this happening and how could I solve the problem? I am wondering is there any PHP configuration file I need to adjust?

I have been stuck with this problem for a long time and googled a lot but didn't find a working solution. I would be appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in my local with the following directory structure

```
root_folder
    |---my_folder
        |__index.php -> (this file contained your code above)
    |---func.php
    |---testimg.png
```

```
<img src='../testimg.png'/> showed my image perfectly.
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I kind of understand where the problem is. I set the root directory on 'my_folder'. (Cause I would like to set this as the public directory on the web server.) Is there a way to use an image outside the root folder?

Comment: I understand the problem now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CassieXu Yeah, you can use any location for your images, as long as its path is accessible.